# R data cleaning

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe (df1)  scrapped as a single column of data .

```
1
2  Amazon Pantry
3  Best Sellerin Soaps & Hand Wash
4
5  Palmolive Hygiene-Plus Sensitive Liquid Hand Wash, 300ml
6  Palmolive Hygiene-Plus Sensitive Liquid Hand Wash, 300ml
7   £0.90
8    ?
9
10  Palmolive Naturals Nourishing Liquid Hand Wash, 300ml
11  Palmolive Naturals Nourishing Liquid Hand Wash, 300ml
12  £0.90
13  ?
14
15  L'Oreal Men Expert Carbon Protect Deodorant 250ml
16  L'Oreal Men Expert Carbon Protect Deodorant 250ml
17  £1.50
```

In order to  clean the data i tried using the below commands such that to get Product and pricing information in 2 separate columns . Can someone let me know if there is an alternate way of doing it .

```
install.packages("splitstackshape")
newdf <- cSplit(df1, "Amazon_Normal_Text2", direction = "long")
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just a thought process...

1. everytime there's a "`ml`," extract information until `ml` going backward until there is a space and store that into volume variable. (`substr`)
2. extract information from `£` to the end of the string and store that into price variable. (`grep`, `regex`, `nchar`)
3. extract from beginning of string until the character location for volume occurrence into product variable (`substr`, `nchar`)

look into `substr`, `nchar`, `grep`, `regex`